# Why are the IF/ELSE commands not working in my batch code?

Tags: batch-file

Trying to get program to run multiplayer co-op, but my batch script isn't working and I think I massively done goofed. Tried getting a friend to help, ended up with this, and it doesn't work at all and I've lost all my progress. Could someone tell me what is wrong here and/or correct it?

```
:hostmpcoop
set /p files="(Optional) Enter stuff to run spaced by -file : "
set /p playercount="Enter number of desired players: "
if "%files%"=="" (
    echo No files entered.
    if not "%playercount%" == "" (
        echo Running vanilla MP
        thing.exe -host %playercount% 
    )else(
        echo You need to specify a playercount!
        goto hostmpcoop
    )
)
if not "%files%"=="" (
    if not "%playercount%"=="" (
        thing.exe -host %playercount% -file %files%
    )else(
        echo You need to specify a playercount!
        goto hostmpcoop
    )
)
if "%files%"==""(
    if "%playercount%"=="" (
        echo "Enter a player count!"
        goto hostmpcoop
    )
)
goto home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need spaces around brackets when else and if are used:

```
:hostmpcoop
set /p files="(Optional) Enter stuff to run spaced by -file : "
set /p playercount="Enter number of desired players: "
if "%files%"=="" (
    echo No files entered.
    if not "%playercount%" == "" (
        echo Running vanilla MP
        thing.exe -host %playercount% 
    ) else (
        echo You need to specify a playercount!
        goto hostmpcoop
    )
)
if not "%files%"=="" (
    if not "%playercount%"=="" (
        thing.exe -host %playercount% -file %files%
    ) else (
        echo You need to specify a playercount!
        goto hostmpcoop
    )
)
if "%files%"=="" (
    if "%playercount%"=="" (
        echo "Enter a player count!"
        goto hostmpcoop
    )
)
```

goto home